# how to get out of "if" loop in c?

Tags: c, if-statement, break

```
if(turn==2)
{
    if(forward)  /*then what to do if this if comes true for coming out of outer loop*/
        if(columnHead>0)
            {
            columnHead--;
            addr[columnHead] |=1<<(rowHead-1);
            }
        else
            {
            columnHead =7;
            addr[columnHead] |=1<<(rowHead-1);
            }
    if(rowTail!=(rowHead-1))
        {
        addr[columnHead+columnSize] &=~(1<<rowTail);
        columnSize++;
        rowTail++;
        }
    else
        {
        addr[columnTail] &=~(1<<columnTail);
        if(columnTail==0)columnTail=8;
        columnTail--;
        }
    back=1;
}
```

I want to come out of outer `if` loop if it satisfies condition `if(forward)`

Comment: There is no if loop. :)

Comment: do you know about `switch`?

Comment: I would **refactor** your method to **extract a function** (from where you can simply `return`). It'll make that code clearer and calling function shorter (and intent more easy to understand).

Comment: not sure why my answer got downvoted but try `if(turn == 2 && !forward)` if forward is a boolean.

Comment: yeah making function is good idea thanks @Adriano

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create function of this code, and return from the block where the condition becomes true.

Answer (score 2):

A standard idiom is to use `while(true){/*your code here*/ break; }` around the whole block and use `break` statements as appropriate which will take you to the end of the while brace. Just remember to include the final `break` or your program will loop.

Whatever you do, don't use a goto as they are considered very poor programming style.

Some folk, from the C days where `while(true)` would issue a compile warning, use `for(;;)` instead.

The odd thing is, thinking about this some more, you could use

```
do {
 /*your code here, using break for premature exit*/
} while (false);
```

which doesn't need the final `break`. Only I've never seen this in production code.

Comment: The last suggestion is quite often used in linux kernel. It's also very convenient in making the expression in macro a single block. (you just need to leave out the final `;` in that case.

Comment: @viraptor but do you still get compile warnings? I'd rather not switch them off.

Comment: Warnings? No, I don't think so. What kind of warning do you get? (and from which compiler?)

Comment: Way back in my University days, the old C compiler gave you warning with while(true) and while(false).

Answer (score 1):

I guess just putting an `else` in there will do what you want. Also, please put braces around big blocks - it makes the `else` part unambiguous.

```
if(turn==2)
{
    if(forward) {
        if(columnHead>0)
            {
            columnHead--;
            addr[columnHead] |=1<<(rowHead-1);
            }
        else
            {
            columnHead =7;
            addr[columnHead] |=1<<(rowHead-1);
            }
    } else {
        if(rowTail!=(rowHead-1))
            {
            addr[columnHead+columnSize] &=~(1<<rowTail);
            columnSize++;
            rowTail++;
            }
        else
            {
            addr[columnTail] &=~(1<<columnTail);
            if(columnTail==0)columnTail=8;
            columnTail--;
            }
        back=1;
    }

}
```

Version after the author's comment:

```
if(turn==2 && !forward) {
    if(rowTail!=(rowHead-1))
        {
        addr[columnHead+columnSize] &=~(1<<rowTail);
        columnSize++;
        rowTail++;
        }
    else
        {
        addr[columnTail] &=~(1<<columnTail);
        if(columnTail==0)columnTail=8;
        columnTail--;
        }
    back=1;
}
```

Comment: +1; I was beginning to question my own sanity as I scrolled past so many answers that didn't say this.

Comment: @viraptor actually what i want is that as soon as "if(forward)" condition comes out to be true then rest of the code should not execute and i should come out of outer if loop.

Comment: You mean from the `columnHead>0` check forwards? That makes that whole part dead code - you can just go for `if (!forward) { the second block here}` in that case and drop the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to go the other direction, that means:
You don't want to check wether
`if(forward)` is true, but instead you want to do `if(!forward)`.

Though you'd need to check what type forward is. I guess it's an integer though.

Comment: yeah it should either be 0 or 1 if it is 1 then i didnt want to continue rest of the code to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving the `return 0;` or `return something;` when you need to get out of the `if`, before that u may want to put the entire code in a `c syntax` function like-

```
    (int)someFunction(int turn, int forward, 
int columnHead, int rowHead, int rowTail, int columnTail)/*have all the arguments with proper types declaration*/{
    //your code with return 0;
    }.
```

Answer (score 0):

why go into the "if" in the first place.

change the outter if to:

```
if(turn==2 && forward) //not sure if your logic required `forward` or `!forward` you were ambiguous 
{
    //...
}
```